# How can I plot a matrix like a chessboard

Tags: python, plot

Hi everybody I need your help with Python code. I have made the below in order o create a Z matrix what I want to do is to plot Z not as I have done but as a chessboard with gradient color shades of blue. That means the minimum of Z matrix which is 0 to be light blue and the maximum 10.81 to be dark blue. All the other intermediate values must have a shadow of blue and the smaller the number the lighter the color and vice versa

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f2(x2, y2):
    return np.sqrt(x2**2+y2**2)

x2 = np.arange(7)
y2 = np.arange(10)

X2,Y2 = np.meshgrid(x2, y2)

Z2 = f2(X2, Y2)
min2=np.min(Z2)
max2 = np.max(Z2)
print(min2)
print(max2)
print(Z2) 

plt.contour(X2, Y2, Z2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `imshow` of the matplotlib library as follows.

```
plt.imshow(Z2, interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: I am sorry where? I apologize I am not familiar with this

Comment: Is that ok now?